# is there a way to set cache for appserviceprovider values?

Tags: laravel, caching

Currently i am trying to set cache for views in appserviceprovider. I tried like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $appServiceProvider = Cache::remember('appServiceProvider', 60, function () {
            View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('home_references', Reference::where('position', 'home')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get());
            $view->with('informations', ContactInformation::first());
            $view->with('header_posts', Post::latest()->limit(4)->get());
        });
    });
    return $appServiceProvider;
}
```

But this method not return value. I shouldn't "return" in here i think. What should i do? I didn't found any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Trying like this is actually working fine:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $view->with('home_references', Cache::remember('home_references', 60, function() {
            return Reference::where('position', 'home')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();}));
        $view->with('informations', Cache::remember('informations', 60, function() {
            return ContactInformation::first();}));
        $view->with('header_posts', Cache::remember('header_posts', 60, function() {
            return Post::latest()->limit(4)->get();}));
    });
```

But that way is repeating itself. I need to set cache as one parameter. In this example 3 query exist. But could be a 30 query. I am looking for better solution.

Comment: **You** have to return something inside a `Cache::remember` function. You'll probably need several of them, to return individual bits like `Reference::where('position', 'home')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get()` from cache, and then pass them to the View composer *outside* of the caching function.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of your `function` in your `Cache::remember` call is what gets cached. If you don't return, you're just caching a `null`.

You're going to want something like this instead:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $homeReferences = Cache::remember('home_references', 60, function () {
            return Reference::where('position', 'home')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
        });

        $informations = Cache::remember('informations', 60, function () {
            return ContactInformation::first();
        });

        $headerPosts = Cache::remember('header_posts', 60, function () {
            return Post::latest()->limit(4)->get();
        });

        $view->with('home_references', $homeReferences);
        $view->with('informations', $informations);
        $view->with('header_posts', $headerPosts);
    });
}
```